# How to FILTER out errors from a list of IMPORTDATA?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-query

Due to a Google Sheets limitation, I am not able to use `ARRAYFORMULA` in conjunction with `IMPORTDATA`.

To circumvent this limitation, I am doing the following:

```
={IMPORTDATA("URL1");IMPORTDATA("URL2");IMPORTDATA("URLN")}
```

For some unknown reason, sometimes 1 random or more URLs don't work and the above formula simply returns `#N/A`, even though some of the requests works.

So, **I would like to filter out the ERRORS** from the results to make the sheet prone to failure and keep the things working, except the ones that "didn't return".

I tried to use the `IFERROR` and `FILTER`, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=QUERY({IFERROR(IMPORTDATA("URL1"));
        IFERROR(IMPORTDATA("URL2"));
        IFERROR(IMPORTDATA("URLN"))},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```